# MVC Core ASP DatePicker not showing value when changing local PC DateFormat

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have datepicker which when the user input value into it and submit, the DB will then be inserted and once the page is refreshed. The value will be shown there. Everything is fine until I change my Local PC DateFormat from "d/M/yyyy" to "M/d/yyyy".

So basically everytime I change my Local PC DateFormat, sometime the value is there and sometime it's not. I have to do something like this to fix it.

If my PC Date is "d/M/yyyy", I have to modify the JS

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

$.datepicker.setDefaults({
     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

});
```

Then the value will be there.
If I change my PC format to "M/d/yyyy", some value of the textbox will be gone and I have to set the datepicker into

```
       $(document).ready(function () {

$.datepicker.setDefaults({
     dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',

});
```

So that the value is there. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Edit: I am using Jquery UI

Comment: yes, that's how it works. even if you select date from the date picker and submit, it will compare the input date with the server (in your case it's dev machine) format, and if the format doesn't match then it will be considered as "null". EOD when you hosting your app , you have to maintain the same format in both app and server.

Comment: @saaduu Umm, how to do I know the default server input date format?

Comment: which datepicker are you using? jQuery UI?

Comment: @AshleyMedway Yes, correct

Comment: @Krayon2 , what application is that ? it's not big deal to know what is the format of server (iis) on which your app is getting hosted.login to it and check for date format which is getting displayed.

Comment: @saaduu Umm, MVC Core 2.0. The problem is that whenever I change my PC Date setting, the value is not there.

Comment: @Krayon2, why do you need to change PC date settings ?

Comment: @saaduu I need to ensure that all date format works because the other people might have different type of format

Comment: @Krayon2, other people might have different types means what ? when you hosted your app on server it cares only the server date format not the client machines formats of every user. ok.

Comment: @saaduu I am not sure whether you are the one misunderstanding or its me. Correct me if I am wrong. So basically, my current PC DateTime is mm/dd/yyyy, I can upload the data and display without any problem. No problem at all. However, if I change my current PC DateTime into mm/dd/yyyy (Why would I do that? Because other user which uses my website in the future, might have this type of PC Date format), and whenever the PC Date format is mm/dd/yyyy, it's not working.

Comment: @saaduu OR are you telling me that in the future when I hosted the MVC Core in a server lets say and other USER with "mm/dd/yyyy" access my website, they won't have any problem whatsoever?

Comment: @Krayon2, yeah you have to make sure that your date format in your date picker and date format in your hosting server should be same .. and once you hosted it will work  that's it. you don't need to care about what is the format of 100 users pc's.

Comment: @saaduu i see. Thanks a lot haha. Thanks so much sir

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC you can set the date format in the model

You could either

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

**Or (assuming you are using razor)**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But both method does not work :(